# Why were these 2 questions closed as 'language-specific'?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12181/5306
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12440/5306

In both cases, I wish to ask about the word as it existed in Latin, French, and English, and possibly other languages entailed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question was deleted by "Community". I don't have access to any more activity on that. As far as I can see, no one flagged or closed the question.

Your second question was about the meanings of **in-** in Latin, which is a language-specific usage issue.

---

PS: to elaborate, I closed the second question because it was of the form "What are the meanings of X in language Y". It seems to be a dictionary look-up question.